# Is it possible to add a bunch of files generated from MySQL to zip using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have generated N number of files by exporting data from mysql using php.
Now is it possible to add those generated files in zip and download them?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible.... using [PHP's ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)

Comment: files generated are same as the table name but i am still unable to get the `foreach()` &  it is showing as **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)**

here is a part of the code that i have written

`while ($rows1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
  {
   $commaList =  implode (',', $rows1);
   $list1= "'".$commaList.".dat'";
   $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $zip_name = "filezip.zip"; // Zip name
   $zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);
   
   
    foreach ($list1 as $file) 
    {
     echo $list1;
     $zip->addFile($file);
    }
   
   $zip->close();`